# Is there a cleaner/better way to write this Contact Manager in React?

Tags: beginner, formatting, react.js

I am learning React by doing a Contact Manager, I am trying to write this code more efficiently. Any ideas...good practise, component splitting, formatting tips are accepted too. Thanks in advance

P.S. Sorry for my English...I am from Italy.

First I used a separate function for everything, then I transformed person variable in an object to use the id and to map the array, then I used the person id to remove people by clicking the side button. Is it possible to do something else?

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./App.css";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <h1 className="title">React Contact Manager</h1>

      <Content />
    </div>
  );
}

class Content extends Component {
  state = {
    people: [],
    name: "",
    age: "",
    telephone: "",
    searchTerm: "",
  };

  id = 1;
  people = [];

  getName = (e) => {
    this.setState({ name: e.target.value });
  };
  getAge = (e) => {
    this.setState({ age: e.target.value });
  };
  getTelephone = (e) => {
    this.setState({ telephone: e.target.value });
  };
  getSearchTerm = (e) => {
    this.setState({ searchTerm: e.target.value });
  };

  AddPerson = () => {
    const newPerson = {
      id: this.id,
      name: this.state.name,
      age: this.state.age,
      telephone: this.state.telephone,
    };
    this.people.push(newPerson);
    this.setState({ people: this.people });
    this.id++;
  };

  RemoveElement = (id) => {
    let newPeople = this.people.filter((person) => person.id !== id);
    this.people = newPeople;
    this.setState({ people: this.people });
  };

  ClearItems = () => {
    this.people = [];
    this.setState({ people: this.people });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="content">
        <div className="inputs">
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="Name"
            className="fname"
            onChange={this.getName}
          />
          <input
            type="number"
            placeholder="Age"
            className="age"
            onChange={this.getAge}
          />
          <input
            type="tel"
            placeholder="Telephone Number"
            className="telephone"
            onChange={this.getTelephone}
          />
        </div>

        <div className="buttons">
          <button className="add" onClick={this.AddPerson}>
            Add
          </button>
        </div>

        <ul className="result">
          {(this.people || []).map((person) => (
            <li key={person.id}>
              <div className="values">
                {person.name + ", " + person.age}
                <span className="telephone_span">{person.telephone}</span>
              </div>
              <button
                className="delete"
                onClick={() => this.RemoveElement(person.id)}
              >
                Remove
              </button>
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
        <button className="clear" onClick={this.ClearItems}>
          Clear
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't add extra properties to the component for things that belong in state.  Delete `this.people` because you already have `this.state.people`.  Move `i` into state.

Of course if you do that you cannot use mutating operations like `++` and `.push()` so you need to make a few changes.  When you are setting a state based on a previous state it is a best practice to use an [update function](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) to get the current state which ensures that you always have the most recent value.

You can do this:

```
this.setState({ people: this.state.people.concat(newPerson) });
```

But it's better to do this:

```
this.setState(prevState => ({ people: prevState.people.concat(newPerson) }));
```

The common code convention in JavaScript is to use camelCase for functions and class methods.  So use `addPerson`, `removeElement`, etc.

You want to be able to clear the inputs when you add a contact.  In order to do that, your `<input>` elements need to be [controlled components](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components) which get their value from state.

Revised Code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <h1 className="title">React Contact Manager</h1>

      <Content />
    </div>
  );
}

class Content extends Component {
  state = {
    people: [],
    name: "",
    age: "",
    telephone: "",
    searchTerm: "",
    id: 0,
  };

  getName = (e) => {
    this.setState({ name: e.target.value });
  };
  getAge = (e) => {
    this.setState({ age: e.target.value });
  };
  getTelephone = (e) => {
    this.setState({ telephone: e.target.value });
  };
  getSearchTerm = (e) => {
    this.setState({ searchTerm: e.target.value });
  };

  addPerson = () => {
    this.setState(state => ({ 
      // clear inputs
      name: "",
      age: "",
      telephone: "",
      // increment id
      id: state.id + 1,
      // add person
      people: state.people.concat({
        id: state.id,
        name: state.name,
        age: state.age,
        telephone: state.telephone,
      })
    }));
  };

  removeElement = (id) => {
    this.setState( state => ({
      people: state.people.filter((person) => person.id !== id)
    }));
  };

  clearItems = () => {
    this.setState({ people: [] });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="content">
        <div className="inputs">
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="Name"
            className="fname"
            value={this.state.name}
            onChange={this.getName}
          />
          <input
            type="number"
            placeholder="Age"
            className="age"
            value={this.state.age}
            onChange={this.getAge}
          />
          <input
            type="tel"
            placeholder="Telephone Number"
            className="telephone"
            value={this.state.telephone}
            onChange={this.getTelephone}
          />
        </div>

        <div className="buttons">
          <button className="add" onClick={this.addPerson}>
            Add
          </button>
        </div>

        <ul className="result">
          {(this.state.people || []).map((person) => (
            <li key={person.id}>
              <div className="values">
                {person.name + ", " + person.age}
                <span className="telephone_span">{person.telephone}</span>
              </div>
              <button
                className="delete"
                onClick={() => this.removeElement(person.id)}
              >
                Remove
              </button>
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
        <button className="clear" onClick={this.clearItems}>
          Clear
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I also changed the get<value> functions to `const handleChange = e => {this.setState({[e.target.name]: e.target.value})}` but now I will update it...Thanks a lot

Comment: That is a good change :)